# Error when pushing to initial commit to GitHub

Tags: git, github, vagrant

I created a new project in GitHub. I then went in to my directory and did the following;

```
git init
git status
git remote add origin https://github.com/path....
git push -u origin master
```

It then asks for my username and password for GitHub. Which I provide. I then get the following error;

```
error: src refspec master does not match any.
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://github.com/path....'
```

I am using Vagrant/VirtualBox.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Git is a distributed version control system. Before you `push` to a remote you have to `commit` locally:

```
git add somefile.txt
git commit
git push -u origin master
```